# Difference between feel and ambiance

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is it correct to say `The feel of this cafe is good`? or `The ambiance of this cafe is good` which is appropriate or more correct? Do they convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 1):

*Ambiance* has the specific meaning of 'the atmosphere of a social venue'.

*Feel* is a more general term; it can mean the same as *ambiance*, but it more often describes the physical sensation of touching something such as a fabric.